# how to find the top three value

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, group-by, google-colaboratory, return-value

but i tried different methods and i still get error on my google collab

**I need to find the top three land areas of region 4 based on income!
**
the table look like this

| land_area | income | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7300 | 500 | 4 |
| 10000 | 499 | 3 |
| 5999 | 9000 | 4 |
| 43222 | 2342 | 2 |
| 3424 | 422 | 1 |
| 23442 | 4234 | 4 |
| 12311 | 112 | 4 |
| 2344 | 423 | 3 |

I'm using google colab for getting my data analytic I gave mini example
i tried using matplotib and then using sorting value and ascending descending .. but still not getting the correct code and the result always error.
im not sure what im doing incorrect

Comment: did the answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# Filter the DF on region=4 using Loc
# sort income (descending)
# the top three values using head

out=df.loc[df['region'].eq(4)].sort_values(['income'], ascending=False).head(3)
out
```

```
land_area   income  region
2   5999    9000    4
5   23442   4234    4
0   7300    500     4
```

or

```
# sort the DF on region (ascending), income (descending)
# group on region, and take the top three values using head

out=df.sort_values(['region','income'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby(['region'], as_index=False).head(3)

out
```

```
land_area   income  region
4   3424    422     1
3   43222   2342    2
1   10000   499     3
7   2344    423     3
2   5999    9000    4
5   23442   4234    4
0   7300    500     4
```